# How to return a reference of the top object in a stack c++

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, stack, nodes

I am attempting to create a peek()/top() function for my Stack class using templates, and have this issue where I am unsure of how to return the topmost object of the stack. So far, I have been able to check if the top object is empty, if it's not then move a current pointer to point to the head of the Stack and return that pointer's data. However, this returns an int and I am wanting to return a reference to the object, not the data in the object. Any ideas of how to do this?

Stack.h

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> 

template <typename T>
class LStack
{
    public:
    //mutator member functions
    LStack(){numofstacks = 0;}
    ~LStack(){}

    void push(const T& obj) //insert obj at the top of the stack
    {
        data.add_to_head(obj);
        numofstacks = numofstacks + 1;
    }

    T pop() //remove and return the top object from the stack, error if stack is empty
    {   
        if (is_empty()){
            std::cout << "Stack is empty" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            data.remove_from_head();
            numofstacks = numofstacks - 1;
            if (is_empty()){
                exit(0);
            }
            else{   
            data.move_to_head();
            return data.get_current();
            }
        }           
    }

//return a reference to the ***OBJECT** at the top of the stack, NULL if the stack is empty, (also refered to as top())
    T& peek() 
    {
        if (is_empty()){
            std::cout << "Stack is empty" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            data.move_to_head();
            return data.get_current();  // Need to return reference to object here

        }
    }

    bool is_empty() const //return a boolean indicating whether the stack is empty
    {
        return (size() == 0);
    }

    int size() const  //return the number of objects in the stack
    {
        return numofstacks; 
    }

    private:
    LinkedList<T> data;
    int used;
    int numofstacks;

};
```

LinkedList

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> 

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    public:     
        LinkedList() //constructor
        {
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
            current = NULL;
            list_length=0;
        }
        ~LinkedList()//destructor since we're creating the linked list on the heap
        {
            while (head != NULL)
            {
              remove_from_head();
            }
            tail = NULL;//not sure if in or out of while loop
        }

        LinkedList(T& item)
        {
            head = new Node<T>(item);
            tail = head;
            current = tail;
            list_length = 1;
        }

        void add_to_head(const T& item)
        {
            if (list_length == 0){ //if list is empty
                head = new Node<T>(item);
                tail = head;
                current = tail;
                list_length = 1;
            }
            else //Else if list is not empty.. Insert node at the head
            {       
                Node<T>* head_insert = new Node<T>(item);       
                head->set_prev(head_insert);
                head_insert->set_next(head);
                head = head_insert;
                list_length++;
                head_insert = NULL;
            }
        }

        void add_to_tail(const T& item)
        {           
            if (list_length == 0){
                head = new Node<T>(item);
                tail = head;
                current = tail;
                list_length = 1;
            }
            else  //insert node at tail 
            {               
                Node<T>* tail_insert = new Node<T>(item);
                tail->set_next(tail_insert);
                tail_insert->set_prev(tail);
                tail = tail_insert;
                list_length++;
                tail_insert = NULL;         
            }
        }

        void remove_from_head()
        {
            if (list_length == 0){
                return;
            }
            else if (list_length == 1){

                delete head;
                head = NULL;
                tail = NULL;
                current = NULL;
                list_length--;
                return;
            }
            else
            {   
                Node<T>* temp_head = head;
                head = temp_head->get_next();
                delete temp_head;
                list_length--;
                temp_head = NULL;
            }
        }

        void remove_from_tail()
        {
            if (list_length == 0){
                return;
            }
            else if (list_length == 1)
            {
                delete head;
                head = NULL;
                tail = NULL;
                current = NULL;
                list_length--;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Node<T>* temp_tail = tail;
                tail = temp_tail->get_prev();
                delete temp_tail;
                list_length--;
                temp_tail = NULL;               
            }
        }   

        std::size_t size()
        {
            return list_length;
        }

        T get_current() 
        {
            return current->get_data();
        }                       

        void forward()
        {
            current = current->get_next();
        }

        void back()
        {
            current = current->get_prev();
        }

        void move_to_head()
        {
            current = head;
        }

        void move_to_tail()
        {
            current = tail;
        }

        private: //private members
        Node<T>* head; //point to start of list
        Node<T>* tail; //point to end of list
        Node<T>* current; //optional - used to refer to a node in our list
        std::size_t list_length;
};
```

Error Message

> In file included from main.cpp:1:0: LStack.h: In instantiation of ‘T&
>   LStack::peek() [with T = int]’: main.cpp:29:19:   required from
>   here LStack.h:52:28: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of
>   type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
>       return data.get_current(); // Need to return reference to object here

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: `get_current()` returns by value, not by reference. For `LStack` to return a reference to some element, its underlying `LinkedList` needs to provide a way to obtain a reference to that element.

Answer (score 0):

This method in your linked list:

```cpp
T get_current()
```

returns an rvalue of type T. rvalues are constant by definition. Change to prototype of get_current to:

```cpp
T& get_current()
```

You may also need to change the return type for Node::get_data to return a reference as well.

Comment: If `get_current()` still returns by value, then `const T& peek() { return data.get_current();}` would return a dangling reference - a reference to a temporary that has already been destroyed by the time the function returns. Any attempt by the caller to actually use that reference would exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that as much as it may seem to you like you want to do this, you really don't, because there's no way to do it cleanly. Even having `pop()` return the top object by value is highly problematic. In particular, if the copy constructor for the stored type can throw, it's pretty much a disaster waiting to happen--if the copy constructor throws as its trying to copy the return value, the situation is basically unrecoverable. The value has already been removed from the stack, but it isn't being returned to the caller, so it's completely lost.

The standard library gets around this by not having pop return anything. So, you pop an item from the stack in two steps: first you use `top()` to get the top item on the stack, then you use `pop()` to just remove the item on top of the stack:

```
auto top_item = your_stack.top();
your_stack.pop();
```

If the copy constructor throws as you're trying to retrieve the top-of-stack item, then the `your_stack.pop()` won't execute, so the stack hasn't been affected--the top item remains there. The `pop()` only executes if you've already successfully retrieved the top item into `top_item`.

Unfortunately, this is a little clumsy to use.

Even more unfortunately, since we're using two steps to pop the top item, it's essentially impossible to make this thread-safe--for that, you just about have to ensure that retrieving the item and removing it from the stack are a single atomic operation--either both of them happen without anything else interfering, or else neither one happens at all.

There is a design that meets that requirement, and (at least arguably) isn't quite as clumsy to use:

```
void pop(T &t) { 
    t = storage.back();
    storage.pop_back();
}
```

Much like the previous example using the standard stack, if the `t=storage.back();` line throws an exception, then the `storage.pop_back();` simply won't execute--you haven't retrieved an item, but the items on the stack remain undisturbed.

For a simple concurrent stack, you could add a mutex and change the return type to `bool`, indicating whether the operation succeeded or not (again, you can't follow the typical single-threaded pattern of "if (!stack.empty()) stack.pop()`, since you're back to using two separate operations, so even if you find a non-empty stack, by the time you try to pop it, some other thread may have already done so, and your attempt at popping will fail.